# Key Error 0 while plotting in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have a dataframe with numbers (float32) stored in them, whos index's are A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, where A's are the values and B's are the errors associated with that value, I am trying to run it through a loop to plot A1 with A2 (and their errors) and A1 with A3 (again with errors), however partway through the loop I am getting a KeyError: 0. The plotting is done with a function call in a loop, the loop works fine (removing the errorbars commands makes it run, but of course without the plotted errors), it also does several plots before it gets to one that breaks it. This is done in python.

Here is the function (with dataframe already loaded in and I can find values in it):

```
fig = plt.figure('hello')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.ylim(-2, 1.5)
plt.xlim(-2, 1.5)
plt.xlabel('A1')
plt.ylabel('A2 (green) A3 (blue)')
ax.scatter(df[A1], df[A2], c='g')
plt.errorbar(df[A1], df[A2], fmt='g', xerr=df[B1], yerr=df[B2])
ax.scatter(df[A1], df[A3], c='b')
plt.errorbar(df[A1], dat[A3], fmt='b', xerr=df[B1], yerr=df[B3])
plt.savefig('figure' +str(df[i]))
ax.clear()
```

Comment: See [mcve] and provide one in your question to get help.

Comment: I think it's ````df[i]```` in savefig that throws the error if your ````i```` takes numerical values. How do you want to format your filename?